# Why do we use @ before the variables in if condition in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having little bit of confusion as to why we use @ in if condition in PHP

Example

```
foreach ($date as $value) {
        if(@$data[$value] != ""){
            $data[$value] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data[$value]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: We don't, if we're writing safe code. It suppresses errors, and should almost never be used.

Comment: In this case they are using `if(@$data[$value] != "")` where the `@` likly suppresses undefined index errors.  A better use would be `if(!empty($data[$value]))`.  Also to note the difference between `$date` and `$data` can cause some readability issues.  It's very easy to confuse one for the other (well for my dyslexic self that is)

Comment: In this specific case, is the "old way" to emulate something like ?? as this is not per-se an error in php to access an undefined cell in an array. If the cell is not defined and u do this if, u get a warning about an undefined ..., If u want to use proper code, do isset($data['value] && $data['value'] !=''

Comment: thanks to all...u guided me very-well